# Combine two repositories with a common history into one with two branches

Tags: git, git-merge

Consider  a repository  which  was  duplicated onto  another
location. Both  the original and copy  received new commits,
but they share the same past history of commits.

```
   ./dirA                          ./dirB

   * D: new commit                 * F: new commit
   |                               |
   * C: new commit                 * E: new commit
   |                               |
   * B: last common commit         * B: last common commit
   |                               | 
  ...                             ...
   |                               |
   * A: initial commit             * A: initial commit
```

How can  I combine both so  that all the common  commits are
preserved (including  dates) and  from the  diverging commit
forward the history is kept on two different branches?

```
   ./combined

   * D <dirA>  * F <dirB>
   |           |
   * C         * E: new commit
     \       /
      \    /
       \ /
        V 
        * B: last common commit
        |
       ...
        |
        * A: initial commit
```

Comment: _"Consider a repository which was duplicated onto another location"_ - so they're the same repo, but the histories diverge at commit B? What about adding one as a remote of the other and try merging a branch?

Comment: Exactly. Up until B, they are the same. Wouldn't a merge create another commit merging both? I'd like to have them combined, with the divergences on different branches. Sorry if I'm misinterpreting something.

Comment: Try adding dirA as a remote on dirB and fetching it `git fetch dirA`? You can then check out F

Comment: No need to merge. Just add the other repo as a remote, fetch and then create _another_ local branch on the branch from the other remote... then you have what you are asking for,

Comment: Thank you. I got it working. Simpler than I imagined. Shall we post it as an answer just for reference?

Comment: @eftshift0 Thank you. So the act of creating another local branch on top of the remove is what effectively saves it into the repository? When testing here, after the fetch if I simply remove the remote the whole history goes together. If I create the local branch on top of the remote branch and then remove the remote, it stays. Is that correct?

Comment: Not exactly when you remove the remote.... a branch is just a pointer to a commit. When you remove the remote, you would remove the remote reference (in your local) to that commit.... but git won't get rid of the commits at that moment... it would happen some time later when garbage collection takes place. Until that happens, the commit would still be in your object DB and you would still be able to use it with the id, if so you wished.

Comment: @sidyll: about commits staying, test the following: write down the sha of the top most commit in `dirB`, and go to `dirA` and run `git log <sha>` (or `git log --graph --oneline <sha>`). When you "delete the remote", the *name* `other/branch-name` disappears, but the commit remains. If it is not referenced (e.g: pointed by a branch or tag, or part of the history of a branch or tag), it will get garbage collected *later* (as eftshift0 correctly said), but right now you can tag it or create a branch pointing to it or ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the commits are actually the same (e.g: both commits `B` have the same hash) :

just put both histories in one common repo, and choose how you want to name your branches :

- option 1: update `dirA` with commits from `dirB` :

```
cd dirA
git remote add other ../dirB  # <- dirB is a path on the same local computer correct ?
                              # please update your question if this weren't the case

git fetch other

# you should now have all commits from dirB available as commits in A,
# and branches in repoB available as named remote banches `other/*` :
git branch masterB other/master
git branch wokrBranch <E>
```

- option 2: do not alter `dirA` or `dirB`, join them in a separate repo:

```
# clone one of your directories, and add the second one as a remote:
git clone dirA mergeRepo
cd mergeRepo
git remote add other ../dirB

# then same as above:
git fetch other
git branch masterB other/master

# with the above commands: 'dirA' is 'origin', 'dirB' is 'other'

# inspect the history ...
# if satisfied with the result, you can push new branches:
git push origin masterB
```